# Finding missing elements in a List

Tags: python, list

Hello I have a List with a lot of element in it. These are numbers and ordered but some numbers are missing.

Example: `L =[1,2,3,4,6,7,10]`

Missing: `M = [5,8,9]`

How can I find missing numbers in Python?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should do the trick

```
def missing_elements(L):
    s, e = L[0], L[-1]
    return sorted(set(range(s, e + 1)).difference(L))

miss = missing_elements(L)
```

Answer (score 5):

Take the difference between the sets:

```
set(range(min(L),max(L))) - set(L)
```

If you are really crunched for time and `L` is truly sorted, then

```
set(range(L[0], L[-1])) - set(L)
```

Comment: Or equivalent and not needing to build another set... `set(L).difference(range(min(L), max(L)))` ?

Comment: Indeed @JonClements, although I still believe this will hash all the elements in the iterable passed to difference under the hood.

Comment: For `L =[1,2,3,4,6,7,10]`, your code gives the output as `{10}`. That's not what the OP wants. Change the order of subtraction

Comment: good call @Bazingaa. Or we can just include the last element.

Comment: You again got it wrong. Your edited version with `+1` returns an empty set for `L =[1,2,3,4,6,7,10]`. The required output is `[5,8,9]` so plz edit your answer with the correct subtraction order. I would also convert the final set into list as the OP wants list as an output.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
L =[1,2,3,4,6,7,10]
M = [i for i in range(1, max(L)) if i not in L]
# If 0 shall be included replace range(1, max(L)) to range(max(L))
```

Answer (score 2):

With a comprehension it would look like this:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,6,7,10]

M = [i for i in range(min(L), max(L)+1) if i not in L]

M

#[5,8,9]
```

And a fun one, just to add to the bunch:

```
[i for a, b in zip(L, L[1:]) for i in range(a + 1, b) if b - a > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L =[1,2,3,4,6,7,10]
R = range(1, max(L) + 1)
   > [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

M = list(set(R) - set(L))
    > [5,8,9]
```

Note that M will not necessarily be ordered, but can easily be sorted.